# Deploy ASP.NET Website (.NET 2) using Visual Studio 2012

Tags: asp.net, deployment, visual-studio-2012, vs-web-site-project

I have an ASP.NET 2 Website that I need to deploy using Visual Studio 2012. I need a compiled single Assembly.

Comment: Is it a web site, or a web application project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest version of the publish feature (described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/11/20/new-web-publish-updates.aspx) and available with the Azure 1.8 SDK) now supports pre-compilation for both Web Site projects and Web Application projects.  This is the [replacement for Web Deployment Projects](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/08/06/plans-regarding-website-projects-and-web-deployment-projects.aspx), which was previously available for VS2005/2008/2010.  It also supports all of the publish scenarios equally for both types of projects (e.g. web.config transforms, database deployment, etc...).